# Mariadb update column during load data of CSV

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger, csv

I am loading .csv files into Mariadb 10.6 using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

There is a DATE column called `posted_on` in the inbound data, and I need store the month name in another field `monther`, ideally as part of the loading process.

If posted_on = '2023-10-13' then monther = 'October'

I assumed a trigger would be appropriate and have tried variations (added NEW., before/after) on the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_monther` after INSERT ON `qn_txs` 
     FOR EACH ROW 
 UPDATE qn_txs SET NEW.qn_txs.`monther` = MONTHNAME(`posted_on`);
```

But can't get past the dreaded ERROR 1442 (HY000) at line 1: Can't update table 'qn_txs' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Any thoughts? Is a different approach needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you can't UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT in a trigger for the same table. This could cause an infinite loop of triggers.

But you don't need to use UPDATE if you are changing values in the row being inserted. If you `SET NEW.ColumnName` in a trigger, that changes the value for that column in the row that spawned the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_monther` BEFORE INSERT ON `qn_txs` 
     FOR EACH ROW 
 SET NEW.`monther` = MONTHNAME(NEW.`posted_on`);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/qC9iCUbg

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately, the CREATE is throwing an error. Looks good to me though.
``` syntax to use near '.monther = MONTHNAME(`posted_on`)' at line 3 ```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had done `NEW.tableName.columnName`. You don't need the table name in that. It is implicit that `NEW.columName` is naturally based on the table the trigger is defined for. I have edited my answer above to fix that.

Comment: I just checked the MariaDB documentation to see if I could refer you to a page that explains this, but they don't state it! Sigh. Another reason that I avoid MariaDB — the documentation is much less complete than that of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Rabbit hole time. The above trigger says, "Error Code: 1362 Updating of NEW row is not allowed in AFTER trigger". So I just tried BEFORE and it created. But the load now throws, "ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'posted_on' in 'field list'" Where `posted_on` and `monther` are both physically in the table.

Comment: This will teach me a lesson I have known for a long time: test solutions posted on Stack Exchange, or you're bound to miss some details. I edited the above. Both column references must have the `NEW` prefix, so they are interpreted as columns of the row that spawned the trigger. And yes, you can `SET` column values only in a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: That did it! I never would have figured that out. PS, your book is in my shopping cart.

Comment: Thanks for checking out my book! Make sure you get the revised 2022 edition. Unfortunately, I didn't realize that when I renamed it "SQL Antipatterns Volume 1" that Amazon treats that as a whole new book instead of a second edition of the first book. Here's a direct link to the publisher's page: https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/

Comment: [Edited into docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-overview/#creating-a-trigger) thanks @BillKarwin

Comment: @danblack Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with a `TRIGGER`, use a temporary variable inside the `LOAD DATA`:

```
LOAD DATA
...
(a, b, c, @date, e, f, ...) 
SET date = @date,
    monther = MONTH(@date)
;
```